# Is it possible to use an array as input of Sparkline.Sourcedata with VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sparklines

I would like to use an array instead of a range as data input for a Sparkline.

instead of this:

```
Range("F2").SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkColumn, SourceData:="A2:E2"
```

something like this:

```
Range("F2").SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkColumn, SourceData:=Array(1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use an array as input of SparkLine SourceData with VBA?

***No.*** - Due to [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sparklinegroups.add)
the required `SourceData` string *"represents the **range** to use to create the sparkline."*

Therefore you have to use a range reference of string type,
but you could come close calling a sub procedure with a target and an array argument
inserting the array values to the preceding cells as workaround:

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    Dim arr: arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    AddSparkLine Sheet1.Range("F2"), arr
End Sub

Sub AddSparkLine(target As Range, arr)
'a) count zero-based array elements
    Dim n As Long: n = UBound(arr) + 1
'b) define data range
    Dim dataRng As Range: Set dataRng = target.Offset(, -n).Resize(1, n)
'c) write array to data range
    dataRng = arr
'd) define SourceData string
    Dim srcData As String: srcData = target.Parent.Name & "!" & dataRng.Address
'e) insert spark lines
    target.SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkColumn, SourceData:=srcData
End Sub
```